# Using SignalR in full ajax navigated web pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, signalr

I'm trying to accommodate myself to SignalR.
But I need a gold point to completely understand it. I feel one step away from snatch...

My codes:

**Javascript:**

```
            $(function() {
                var connection = $.connection.signalR;

                connection.client.broadcastTotalOnline = function (totalOnlineUser) {
                    $('#TotalOnline').html(totalOnlineUser);
                };

                $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
                    console.log("Connection Started!");
                });
            });
```

**C#:**

```
public class SignalR : Hub
{
    public void SendTotalOnline()
    {
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SignalR>();
        using (var dbContextx = new db_Oyun())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int totalOnlineUser = dbContextx.tbl_User.Count(x => x.Online);
                context.Clients.All.broadcastTotalOnline(totalOnlineUser);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above codes are work perfect but when I call new page to inner content with AJAX.
And then I would like to use same hub, same object and same hub, different object. It not working. Not calling alert; but when I removed above signalR codes, under codes working.

```
        $(function () {
            var connection = $.connection.signalR;
            connection.client.broadcastTotalOnline = function (totalOnlineUser) {
                alert(totalOnlineUser);
            };
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you start your SignalR connection, it examines the `$.connection.signalR.client` object to see if you added any callbacks. If you add a callback using normal assignment after the connection has started, SignalR will not pick up that callback.

To add a callback after the connection has started, you can use [`$.connection.signalR.client.on`](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#callclient):

```
$.connection.signalR.client.on("broadcastTotalOnline", function (totalOnlineUser) {
    alert(totalOnlineUser);
});
```

If you were trying to add a callback to a Hub you didn't already have a callback for before starting your connection, then even using `.on` would not work.

You must have at least one callback hooked up to every hub you plan to use before you start up your connection. The callback that you setup can be a dummy callback that is never called. Adding the callback is just you way of indicating to SignalR that your interested in messages originating from that hub.

You don't need to add any dummy callbacks in your case since you already attach to `broadcastTotalOnline` before starting the connection.

If you want to remove a callback, you can use `$.connection.signalR.client.off` with a reference to the function you previously added:

```
var callback = function (totalOnlineUser) {
    alert(totalOnlineUser);
};

$.connection.signalR.client.on("broadcastTotalOnline", callback);
$.connection.signalR.client.off("broadcastTotalOnline", callback);
```